# Build trigger to create release branch azure devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gated-checkin

We use gitflow. When pull request is created and approved we want to run a gated build. on sucess want to create a release branch from pull request commit. This commit build should get picked up by the gated approval. Could you please direct me to documentation or how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Deploy PR builds using Azure Pipelines documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-pull-request-builds?view=azure-devops)